# Magento auto email send to user after place order magento 1.9

Tags: email

just only want that when a user place the order from my site then an automatic email should be sent to the user email address which contain order details but my Magento dont do it. I have searched in google but I don't fiend an answer. I dont want to use other third party scripts like SMTP Pro.

Answer (score 1):

Starting in Magento EE 1.14.1 and CE 1.9.1, your Magento cron job sends all emails, including transactional emails. You must configure cron for emails to work.